# how to navigate to other page inside initState

Tags: flutter, dart

Instead of using a Stream, I am using Stream.firstWhere to get a Future that will complete only when a specific predicate is met.

```
void initState() {
    stream?.map((value) {
      final currentVal = value.toString();
      final currentParsedVal = int.parse(
        currentVal.substring(1, currentVal.length - 1),
        onError: (source) => -1,
      );
      print("String $currentParsedVal");
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) =>
          Seziurealert()
      );

    })?.firstWhere((value) => value == 2);

  }
```

Seizure Alert function:

```
Seziurealert(){
    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
          return TriggeringAlert(
              device:
              widget.device);
        },
      ),
          (route) => false,
    );

  }
```

I am using Widgetbinding but it is still not navigating, please suggest me a way to navigate to TriggerScreen when the condition is met with firstWhere?